# MongoDb update doesnt work for date in php

Tags: php, mongodb

I try to execute update query for Mongo Db. I use php, and send values that are going to be updated. I send date parameter in milliseconds. But it didn't work. Here is the code;

```
    function updateEventById($id1,$start,$end,$collection)
{
    $this->collection = $this->database->$collection;

    //$start=new MongoDate($start);

    //$end=new MongoDate($end);

    $newdata = array('$set' => array("start.sec" => $start,
                "end.sec" =>  $end ));

    $theObjId = new MongoId($id1["\$id"]);
    $this->collection->update(array("_id" => $theObjId), $newdata);

}
```

Comment: What doesn't work, the commented out code? Tell us how it didn't work and we can tell you why. Also why are you updating the `start.sec` You prolly wanna update `start` with a `MongoDate`

Answer (score 0):

working in codeigniter framework so:

```
  $this->_comment->mongo_db->where(array("idnota" => (int)$idnota, "type" => 3))->set($update)->update($collection);
```

I think the problem is the id which takes a try to compare vardump () to see if it reaches the appropriate parameter

Comment: it gets the id however, it inserts nonvalid date to the values of dates. I am not using any framework

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your case using Mongo Shell, and works fine.

```
> db.col.insert({start: {sec: new Date()}, end: {sec: new Date()}})
> db.col.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50db7b136db4ad2bff518a03"), "start" : { "sec" : ISODate("201
2-12-26T22:32:51.098Z") }, "end" : { "sec" : ISODate("2012-12-26T22:32:51.098Z")
 } }
> db.col.update({_id: ObjectId("50db7b136db4ad2bff518a03")}, {$set: {"start.sec"
: new Date(), "end.sec": new Date()}})
> db.col.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50db7b136db4ad2bff518a03"), "start" : { "sec" : ISODate("201
2-12-26T22:33:33.725Z") }, "end" : { "sec" : ISODate("2012-12-26T22:33:33.725Z")
 } }
>
```

I think you should to use selectCollection function from MongoDB instance and not call to property (As PyMongo works, extending `__getitem__` and `__getattr__`):

```
$this->database->selectCollection($collection)->update(array("_id" => $theObjId), $newdata);
```

Another issue, possibly you should debug your code, because "collection" property class could change its value before to execute a update in another collection.

If you are using MongoClient class, see WriteConcern result.